# Cохранение изменений в настройках программы

Tags: c#, winforms

При загрузке программы я создаю файл:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    File.Create(@"D:\\SettingsForSpamer.txt");
}
```

потом при нажатии на кнопку "сохранить изменения" изменения записываются в файл:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\\SettingsForSpamer.txt", Convert.ToString(numUDtaskbarValue.Value));
}
```

И при загрузке формы изменения считываются:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("SettingsForSpamer.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Close();
        numUDtaskbarValue.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(str);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Файл не найден");
    }
}
```

Но значения numericupdown почему-то не меняется. В чем проблема?

Comment: На строчку `numUDtaskbarValue.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(str);` ставите точку останова, запускаете, смотрите значение переменной `str`, прикидываете в чем же дело...

Comment: Данные записываются в файл по пути `D:`. А считываются из файла по другому пути.

Comment: Кроме того, в конструкторе формы создается _пустой_ файл: все данные в нем стираются. Эту строку кода можно убрать.

Answer (score 1):

Пример на сохранение нескольких значений
[image: пример работы]

Создадим такой класс для хранения настроек

```
class AppSettings
{
    private const char _SEPARATOR_ = ';';
    private const string _BLANK_ = "-";

    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение строки из значений свойств класса установок
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="settings">экз.класса установок</param>
    /// <returns>результат в виде строки</returns>
    public static string GetSettingsLine(AppSettings settings)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Message))
        {
            settings.Message = _BLANK_;
        }
        return $"{settings.Number}{_SEPARATOR_}{settings.Message}{_SEPARATOR_}{settings.Date}";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Попытка разбора строки и получения экземпляра класса установок
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line">строка для разбора</param>
    /// <param name="settings">ссылка на выходной экз.класса установок</param>
    /// <returns>true если строка успешно разобрана</returns>
    public static bool TryParseSettingsLine(string line, out AppSettings settings)
    {
        settings = new AppSettings();
        //делим строку
        string[] sets = line.Split(new char[] { _SEPARATOR_ });
        //проверяем
        if (sets.Length != 3) return false;

        //пытаемся получить число
        if (Int32.TryParse(sets[0], out int num))
            settings.Number = num;
        else return false;

        //получаем сообщение
        if (sets[1] == _BLANK_)
            settings.Message = String.Empty;
        else
            settings.Message = sets[1];

        //пытаемся получить дату
        if (DateTime.TryParse(sets[2], out DateTime date))
            settings.Date = date;
        else return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Код формы такой

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const string _FILE_NAME = "settings.txt";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример";

        _buttonSaveInput.Click += ButtonSaveInput_Click;
        _buttonReadOutput.Click += ButtonReadOutput_Click;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка сохранения установок(значений контролов)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonSaveInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //собираем значения
        var settings = new AppSettings
        {
            Number = Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Round(_numericUpDownInput.Value, 0)),
            Message = _textBoxInput.Text,
            Date = _dateTimePickerInput.Value
        };
        //преобразуем в строку
        string line = AppSettings.GetSettingsLine(settings);

        //запоминаем
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText(_FILE_NAME, line);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Ошибка записи в файл установок: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка чтения установок(значений контролов)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonReadOutput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //читаем файл
        string line = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            line = File.ReadAllText(_FILE_NAME);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Ошибка чтения файла установок: {ex.Message}");
        }

        //пытаемся получить экземпляр класса установок
        if (AppSettings.TryParseSettingsLine(line, out AppSettings settings))
        {
            //присваиваем значения контролам
            _numericUpDownOutput.Value = settings.Number;
            _textBoxOutput.Text = settings.Message;
            _dateTimePickerOutput.Value = settings.Date;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не удалось прочитать все необходимые значения.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, итак, какие ошибки я (и другие люди) смогли заметить:

1. Вы заполняете файл **"D:\SettingsForSpamer.txt"**, а считываете файл **"SettingsForSpamer.txt"**, а **это 2 абсолютно разных** расположения! Заполняемый файл лежит в корне диска D, а считываемый расположен динамически (то есть в зависимости от того где находится исполняемый exe файл).
2. Перед тем как считывать файл **следует проверить его существование**, то есть **вместо** конструкции *try - catch* следует **использовать** `File.Exist(string)`. **ПРАВКА:** Как мне верно подсказали в комментариях, лучше всего использовать и то, и то, то есть проверять файл на существование, не убирая конструкцию *try - catch*.
3. Перед тем как создавать заново файл, тоже следует проверить, не существует ли он, так как, если он существует, он станет пустым.

Немного советов:

1. **Не создавайте** файлы в корнях дисков, это не удобно и не практично, лучше **создавайте их** в папке своего же проекта. Просто написать `File.Create("SettingsForSpamer.txt")` не работает, как минимум у меня, тут лучше написать так `File.Create(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\SettingsForSpamer.txt")`. **ПРАВКА:** Помимо вышесказанного, не следует создавать файлы в корнях дисков и потому, что ингода доступ к таким файлам ограничивается системой.
   Тема на Киберфоруме: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1527847.html
2. **Сохранять данные** лучше **используя Settings.settings**. Пост с Хабра: https://habr.com/ru/post/271483/
3. Мелочь, но всё же, если вы написали строку, начинающуюся с **" @ "** можно писать одинарную **" \ "**

Comment: В целом все верно, но есть нюансы. _вместо конструкции try - catch следует использовать File.Exist_ - перехват исключений нужен в любом случае, ведь на момент вызова метода `File.Exist` файл может существовать, но в следующее мгновение он может быть удален (другой программой, например).

Comment: _Не создавайте файлы в корнях дисков, это не удобно и не практично_ - более важно то, что программа, запущенная с правами обычного пользователя имеет сильно ограниченные права и не имеет доступа ко всей файловой системе.