# Почему не сохраняется текст в файл из TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

textbox создается программно, а после я в программе вожу в него текст и пытаюсь сохранить в файл, но почему то он не сохраняется
Создание TextBox

```
 TextBox EnterName = new TextBox();
            EnterName.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            EnterName.Font = new Font("MicraDi", 11.25F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            EnterName.Location = new Point(3, 35);
            EnterName.Multiline = true;
            EnterName.Name = "EnterName";
            EnterName.Size = new Size(606, 33);
            EnterName.TabIndex = 16;
            panel4.Controls.Add(EnterName);
```

Сохранение

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Новый файл.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine(EnterName.Text);
```

И да так извеняюсь что не по данному вопросу, подскажите как сохранить значение или текст выделенного RadioButton в текстовый файл.

Comment: 1) для простых операций (как у вас) чтения/записи используйте `File.Readxxx()`/`FileWritexxx()`. 2) сохранение значений/настроек пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969129), в этом примере нет `RadioButton`, но по аналогии сохранить/прочитать значение `radioButton1.Checked` легко реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если после ввода значения вы сразу смотрите в файл, там будет пусто. Если хотите сразу увидеть запись в файл, необходимо записать из буфера (см [документацию по StreamWriter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netcore-1.1#methods))

```
sw.Flush();
```

Либо закрыть поток записи, тогда вся информация в буфере будет записана, либо установить свойство (см документация выше):

```
sw.AutoFlush = true;
```

---

По второму вопросу: используйте свойство

```
radioButton.Text;
```

См [документация по RadioButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=netcore-1.1#properties)